# How to unmerge a previously merged commit in git?

Tags: git

Initially I had this:

```
> git log --oneline
a807e4a (HEAD -> master) Add test
.
.
.
4a92648 Improve xyz file
f81cae4 Edit xyz file
.
.
.
7cbf3ec Add gitignore
```

Then I was playing with git, and did some rebases. Now when I log, I get this:

```
> git log --oneline
547748a (HEAD -> master) Add test
.
.
.
ed9f256 Edit xyz file
.
.
.
7cbf3ec Add gitignore
```

As you can see, one commit there has been merged with the commit below it, accidentally. It went unnoticed, and I'm noticing it now. When I refloged, I was able to find the missing commit's hash (I guess its correct). But I don't know how to restore it.

If I do `git reset --merge 4a92648` then it would go to that commit, but I lose the changes I did after that! Can someone help me to get back that commit without losing the changes I made after that. Note that, these changes are only in my local machine and I haven't pushed them yet.

Comment: First, make a full copy of your folder, containing both the working directory and the .git directory. Then experiment in the copy, not the original. This way, if you mess up, you can easily just delete the copy and start over. Then, the first thing I would do would be to rebase again. See if `git rebase 4a92648` works. However, in your illustration, it seems HEAD is pointing to a commit with the same hash. That seems unlikely if you actually rebased away that commit. Can you double-check that the commit is actually gone?

Comment: Just create a new branch at your current head, then you can always get back to this state.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I had put wrong hash values for older log. Now I have corrected them in the question. Head indeed is pointing to a different hash!

Comment: @chepner I had put wrong hash values for older log. Now I have corrected them in the question. Head indeed is pointing to a different hash!

Comment: If someone want, I can show output of `git reflog`. But I would bloat the question. I would need to put atleast 40 lines of it!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, create a temporary branch while experimenting, in this case you could just do:

```
git checkout -b temp_branch
```

Assuming you already are on the branch you want to change.

After that, given that you already have the needed commit hashes, why don't you run a `git rebase -i`? You are allowed to add new lines (and remove them), and not just changing the current ones. For example, if you need to *restore* the lost commit, run:

```
git rebase -i ed9f256^
```

The editor is going to open and show you `pick ed9f256 ...` in the first line. Replace that line with:

```
pick f81cae4 Edit xyz file
pick 4a92648 Improve xyz file
```

In this way you keep the newly applied changes too. Finally, **if you think `master` should reflect the rebased `temp_branch`**, run:

```
git branch -f master temp_branch
```

To update the `master` branch.